# Simplification of: AB + A'C + BC in boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to understand the simplification of the boolean expression:

**AB + A'C + BC**

I know it simplifies to

**A'C + BC**

And I understand why, but I cannot figure out how to perform the simplification through the expression using the boolean algebra identities. I was wondering if someone could show me the steps needed to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you get stuck in the future, try Karnaugh maps. They can help to simplify complicated boolean expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and I know how to use them I just still don't know how to come to the answer with equation simplification.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
F & = AB + A'C + BC \\
 & = AB + A'C + BC(A+A') \\ 
 & = AB + A'C + ABC + A'BC \\
 & = AB + ABC + A'C + A'BC \\ 
 & = AB (1 + C) + A'C (1 + B) \\
 & = AB + A'C
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}AB+A'C+BC\\
&=AB+A'C+BC(A+A')          \quad \text{($A+A'=1$, Complementarity law)}\\
&=AB+A'C+ABC+A'BC\\
&=AB+ABC+A'C+ABC           \quad \text{(Associative law)}\\
&=AB+A'C                 \quad   \text{(Absorption law)}
\end{align*}

Comment: The latest addition of the last but one line is $A'BC$

Answer (score 3):

The two expressions are not equal. The first expression is true when A and B is true and C false but the second is false in this case.

Comment: I might be mistaken but I believe that both equations return true in that instance. Because if A is true and C is false then A'C is true. Meaning the whole second equation is true because it is an OR.

Comment: just for clarification because my notation isn't that common the two equations are **(A*B) + (A*(¬C)) + (B*C)**     and the other one is      **(A*(¬C)) + (B*C)**

Comment: Okay, yes then I understand. I thought you had negation on the variable to the left of your prime character. One way to arrive at the simplified expression is: $AB+A(\neg C)+BC=AB(C+(\neg C))+A(\neg C)(B+(\neg B))+BC(A+(\neg A))=ABC+AB(\neg C)+AB(\neg C)+A(\neg B)(\neg C)+ABC+(\neg A)BC=ABC+AB(\neg C)+A(\neg B)(\neg C)+(\neg A)BC=BC(A+(\neg A))+A(\neg C)(B+(\neg B))=BC+A(\neg C)$

Comment: I know this is late, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In this way , this can be simplified

```
                 LHS = AB+A'C+BC   
                 =  AB+A'C+BC (A+A')                  [ A+A'=1 ]
                  =  AB+A'C+ABC+A'BC
                  = AB+ABC+A'C+A'BC
                  =  AB (1+C)+A'C (1+B)
                  = AB+A'C                           [  1+C=1 ]
                                        =RHS..
```

Comment: Please use [Math Jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to produce beautiful and beautifully formatted mathematical texts.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align*}&= AB+A′C+BC\\
&= AB+A′C+BC(A+A′)\\
&= AB+A′C+ABC+A′BC\\
&= AB+ABC+A′C+A′BC\\
&= AB(1+C)+A′C(1+B)\\
&= AB+A′C\end{align*}$

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Karnaugh map
(8 fields, no dividing lines this time).

See, for example:
*https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh-diagram*

In this diagram only *one* variable changes between two adjacent fields.

B  B  B' B     'Fields
A   1   1  0  0     ABC'  ABC  AB'C AB'C'
A'  0   1  1  0      A'BC' A'BC A'B'C   A'B'C'
  C' C  C  C'

You can see that BC is not adding new 1's'.

So: AB + A'C + BC = AB + A'C

Answer (score -1):

a.b+a'.c+b.c
a.b+a'.c+b.c(a+a')     {Complementary Law}
a.b+a'.c+(a.b.c+a'.b.c)
(a.b+a.b.c)+(a'.c+a'.c.b)
a.b(1+c)+a'.c(1+b)       {As 1+c=1 and 1+b=1}
a.b+a'.c

Answer (score -1):

=AB+A'C+BC
=AB.A'C+BC(A+A')
=AB+A'C+ABC+A'BC
=AB+ABC+A'C+ABC
=AB+A'C